# Better way to create edge list matrix using an adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix as follows: (adjacency matrix)

```
   R S K
A 1 1 0
B 0 1 0
C 1 0 0
D 1 0 0
E 0 0 1
F 0 0 1
```

The objective is to get a square matrix, which will have dimension as number of rows and columns in the above matrix. This matrix would be filled using the above matrix (if A-S is 1, then S-A should be also 1) and the results should look like this (edge-list matrix),

```
 A B C D E F R S K
A 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
C 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
R 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
S 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
K 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

> I have written the following code which works well, I was wondering if there is an efficient way to achieve the above result?

```
#READ THE FIRST DATA FRAME
df <- read.table(text = "R S K
1      1     0
0      1     0
1      0     0
1      0     0
0      0     1
0      0     1", header=TRUE)

#INPUT THE ROW NAMES IN df
rownames(df)<-LETTERS[1:6]
#INITIALIZE A SQUARE MATRIX WITH #ROWS=#COLUMNS=#(ROWS OF df)+#(COLUMNS OF df)
godmat<-matrix(0, nrow =  sum(dim(df)), ncol= sum(dim(df)))
# ASSING ROW AND COLUMN NAMES
rownames(godmat) <- c(rownames(df),colnames(df))
colnames(godmat)  <- c(rownames(df),colnames(df))

#fill the matrix using df
for (i in colnames(godmat))
  for (j in colnames(godmat)) {
    godmat[i,j]=tryCatch({ godmat[i,j]<-df[which(rownames(df)==i), which(colnames(df)==j)]}, error = function(cond) { return(0)})
    #godmat[j,i]=godmat[i,j]
  }

#fill the matrix using df by copying the elements already filled
for (i in colnames(godmat))
  for (j in colnames(godmat)) {
   godmat[j,i]=godmat[i,j]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a `matrix` of 0's based on the `length` of `unique` `dimnames` of the first dataset. Based on the `match` between the `rownames` and `colnames` of both the datasets, we assign the values of 'm1' to 'm2', take the transpose and add it with 'm2'

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(dimnames(m1)))
m2 <- matrix(0, length(un1), length(un1), dimnames = list(un1, un1))
i1 <- match(rownames(m1), rownames(m2), nomatch =0)
j1 <- match(colnames(m1), rownames(m2), nomatch = 0)
m2[i1, j1] <- m1
t(m2)+m2
#  A B C D E F R S K
#A 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
#B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
#C 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#D 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
#F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
#R 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#S 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#K 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. One question @akrun, will unlisting will keep the order intact ? I understand this will not have any effect on the solution you have provided.

Comment: @vivek  If you want a custom order, then you may have to sort it based on that with `match` or `factor`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `merge` and `rbind` and `cbind` in base R:

```
nm <- rownames(df)
m <- matrix(0,nrow(df),nrow(df),dimnames = list(nm,nm))
p1 <- merge(m, df, by = "row.names")[-1]
p2 <- cbind(t(df),matrix(0,ncol(df),ncol(df),dimnames = list(names(df),NULL)))
colnames(p2) <- c(nm, names(df))
res <- rbind(p1,p2)
rownames(res) <- c(nm, names(df))

 # A B C D E F R S K
# A 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
# B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
# C 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# D 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
# F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
# R 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
# S 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# K 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

`p1` is where adjacency matrix is attached column-wise. `p2` is the row-wise one and then `rbind(p1,p2)`. These two are the main parts. The rest are just setting the names.